# is there a way reinstall gnome like it is installed in ubuntu minimal install

Tags: gnome, 22.04

is there a way to install gnome shell like it is in ubuntu minimal install? also I deleted too many gnome packages so i had to reinstall gnome and the interface is weird.I think it is because i dont have the right packages, is there a way to resolve this and if it helps the packages i installed are installed gnome-shell and ubuntu-gnome-desktop.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Minimal I never used Ubuntu minimal myself. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the metapackage `ubuntu-desktop-minimal`.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop-minimal
```